# Grails, JQuery, GWT REST Interface

Tags: jquery, json, gwt, rest, grails

we are just in the beginning of a new project. We want to use Grails on server side and GORM pages(for html pages rendering and JQuery support) and GWT(for rich gui backend interface). Later we planned to extend our application by devices for Android or Iphone. Therefore we planned to use a RESTful(with JSON) interface for all service access.

Now is my question is this approach a little bit overkill? Because we are now struggling to find the right structure for our REST interface. Of course we want to setup the interface so that I can be reused by all clients instead of providing e.g. GWT specific RPC service and the JQuery html interface is rendered by GORM only.

- Is this approach a little bit overkill?
- What is the easiest way to define a RESt service?(just look what for data I need, name the service and go for it?)
- How would you suggest to put the rendering on HTML side? Only forward in the action to the appropriate view(gorm) and let JQuery only communicate via the REST service and rendering of JSON data instead of using gorm specific form logic?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't sound like overkill if you're planning to create mobile device clients.  There are plenty of good resources on how to implement REST in Grails (I've been primarily following the book [Grails in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988932) and [this link](http://www.suryasuravarapu.com/2009/06/rest-crud-with-grails.html), as well as [this guide to RESTful services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596801688)).

As for HTML rendering, in a simple web-only app I'd say just pass GORM objects into your normal views, that would probably be easiest.  But GWT does have good support for services, plus if you use your services in the web front end, this will give you a complete set of usage scenarios for your REST services that you'll be able to use on the mobile device apps.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can consider is Spring ROO.

Spring ROO provides out of box REST and GWT support but Grails is totally our of equation. I really like the ROO's REST interface. Can be easily made to work with things like jQuery's jqGrid.

GWT with ROO can prove to be a pretty decent stack. ROO, although not as mature, competes in the same space as grails, but uses Java instead of Groovy. And once you pick GWT, adding jQuery would just complicate your codebase.

As for mobile development support in GWT, checkout this [Google I/O talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N1aCo5LvMf8)